# Query to find all bars that sell three different beers at the same price

Tags: php, mysql

Query to find "All bars that sell three different beers at the same price?"

My Tables are

Sells(bar,beer,price) - bar - foreign Key.. 
Bars(name,addr) - name primary key.

I thought of something like this but that dosent seem to work ...

```
 Select A.bar As bar , B.bar as bar  
 From Sells AS A, Sells AS B 
 Where A.bar = B.bar and A.beer <> B.beer  
 Group By(A.beer) 
 Having Count(Distinct A.beer) >= 2
```

Is this the correct SQL query ?

Comment: Well there's a subject that'll attract folks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
Select A.bar
From Sells AS A
JOIN Sells AS B ON (A.bar = B.bar AND A.price = B.price 
    AND A.beer <> B.beer)
JOIN Sells AS C ON (A.bar = C.bar AND A.price = C.price 
    AND A.beer <> C.beer AND B.beer <> C.beer)
```

In MySQL in particular, the join solution is likely to be more efficient than `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ...
From Bars As B
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From Sells As S1
                Where Exists    (
                                Select 1
                                From Sells As S2
                                Where S2.bar = S1.bar
                                    And S2.beer <> S1.beer
                                    And S2.price = S1.price
                                )
                    And S1.Bar = B.name
                Having Count(*) = 3     
                )
```